# Perl simple filehandling of text

Tags: perl

What this program is meant to do is that it reads a text file which looks like:

Item \t\t Price

apple \t\t 20

orange \t\t 50

lime \t\t 30

I'm using split function to split these 2 columns and then i should apply a -25% discount on all items and print it out to a new file. My code so far does what i want but the new text file has a '0' value under my last number in price column. I also get 2 errors if i run it with "use warnings" which are:

Use of uninitialized value $item in multiplication * ...

Use of uninitialized value $item[0] in concatenation (.) ...

I should also tell total number of items calculated but i get like 5 1's instead of 5. (11111 instead of 5)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename  = 'shop.txt';
if (-e $filename){
    open (IN, $filename);
}
else{
    die "Can't open input file for reading: $!";
}
open (OUT,">","discount.txt") or die "Can't open output file for writing:    $!";

my $header = <IN>;

print OUT $header;

while (<IN>) {
    chomp;
    my @items = split(/\t\t/);
    foreach my $item ($items[1]){
        my $discount = $item * (0.75);
        print OUT "$items[0]\t\t$discount\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The script should work if there are no empty lines, and all items are separated by two tabs. The warnings you get indicate that that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is too complicated and not clear what are you doing in foreach loop and you are not skipping empty lines. Keep it simple:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use v5.10;

<>; # skip header
while(my $line = <>)
{
    chomp $line;
    next unless ($line);

    my ($title, $price ) = split /\s+/, $line;
    if( $title && defined $price )
    {
        $price *= 0.75;
        say "$title\t\t$price";
    }
}
```

and run like

```
perl script.pl <input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What should i do if i want total number of items calculated but only get 11111 instead of 5?

Comment: Not sure i understand what you want. Make counter and increment it on each valid entry.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename  = 'shop.txt';
if (-e $filename){
    open (IN, $filename);
}
else{
    die "Can't open input file for reading: $!";
}
open (OUT,">","discount.txt") or die "Can't open output file for writing:    $!";

my $header = <IN>;
my $item;
my $price;

print OUT $header;

while (<IN>) {
  chomp;
  ($item, $price) = split(/\t\t/);

  my $discount = $price*0.75;
  print OUT "$item $discount\n";

}
```

This should help! :)

Comment: Some explanation of what you did would be helpful. Answers that are just code dumps and "try this" or "hope this helps" are less useful.

Comment: Yeah sure! :)
Instead of storing it in an array (@items), there is a way to store both item and price variables separately, as shown: 
($item, $price) = split(/\t\t/);
The argument given in split is the separator by which the strings are separated. In this case it is double tab. hence \t\t.
Then the operation you need to perform can be done on price easily.

Answer (score 1):

If the total item count isn't very important to you:

```
$ perl -wane '$F[1] *= 0.75 if $. > 1; print join("\t", @F), "\n";' input.txt
```

Output:

```
Item    Price
apple   15
orange  37.5
lime    22.5
```

If you really need the total item count:

```
$ perl -we 'while (<>) { @F = split; if ($. > 1) { $F[1] *= 0.75; $i++ } print join("\t", @F), "\n"; } print "$i items\n";' input.txt
```

Output:

```
Item    Price
apple   15
orange  37.5
lime    22.5
3 items
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this approach

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %items;
my $filename  = 'shop.txt';
my $discount = 'discount.txt';

open my $in, '<', $filename or die "Failed to open file! : $!\n";
open my $out, ">", $discount  or die "Can't open output file for writing:    $!";

print $out "Item\t\tPrice\n";
my $cnt = 0;
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    chomp $line;
    if (my ($item,$price) = $line =~ /(\w.+)\s+([0-9.]+)/){
        $price = $price * (0.75);
        print $out "$item\t\t$price\n";
        $items{$item} = $price;
        $cnt++;
    }
}
close($in);
close($out);

my $total = keys %items;

print "Total items - $total \n";
print "Total items - $cnt\n";
```

Using regex capture groups to capture the item and price (using \w.+ in case the item is 2 words like apple sauce), this will also prevent empty lines from printing to file.

I also hard coded the Item and Price header, probably a good idea if you are going to be using a consistent header.

Hope it helps

---**Update** ----

I added 2 examples of a total count in my script.  The first one is using a hash and printing out the hash size, the second method is using a counter.  The hash option is good except if your list has 2 items that are the same in which case the key of the hash will be overridden with the last item found which shares the same name.  The counter is a simple solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but to be honest i try to avoid regex as much as possible because i find it so confusing but it may also be because i've started recently.

Comment: I know the feeling, When I started using perl I did the same but since then I find regex to be super power and very useful and I use it all the time.  In your example personally I prefer using regex in case your shop file decides to change or some one uses 4 spaces in stead of using a tab (which would be ignored with split('\t\t') but in any case it looks like you've gotten enough help on this thread to get you going.

Comment: Yes thanks again, do you know how i can print out total number of items from my .txt files? Let's say i have 10 items with prices in the text file so i want 10 to be printed out but i don't know how

Comment: I made a change to my above code to give you 2 examples of how you could print out a count total.  Both ways work fine with the counter method being a little bit more robust.  Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort